# how to solve the javascript files are blocked every 3 days in magento2?

Tags: magento2

We are using Magento2 v2.0.0 with Ves Need Theme. Our Site was blocked by web guards 3 days once. Please give any solutions to solve.

Comment: After blocking js , I ran the following commands.
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
rm -rf pub/static/*
rm –rf var/view_preprocessed/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
set permission for var, pub/static, pub/media
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush.
After that  It is working fine. But after 3 days, again it is blocked by web Guards. I Could not find , What is the issues are? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a 'web guard' is, but it sounds like something in your website is triggering the blocking. It's unlikely to be something in Magento core which is triggering this behaviour, so I would progressively disable your customisations (themes, extensions, etc) to narrow down which one seems to be the problem.